Real Time Notification API using SignalR has high response time
Real Time Notification API using SignalR has high response time, Is there a different tool or framework that can do better. C# .NET Core Web API
I am expecting another tool i can use to implement Real time notifications(C# .NET)

What is your current response time and what is your target response time?

Current response time is 12seconds, want to achieve less that 1 second

12 seconds is way too high, something is wrong there. This also happens when running locally? How big is the data? Which transport is it using?
